# Spring-boot Issue in retrieving AWS-Parameter store values which are configured in application.yaml

Tags: spring-boot

I am migrating an spring-boot application from 2.2.6 to 2.6.6 due to recent RCE issue.

My application is hosted in AWS. I have application.yaml, where we configured few values to retrieve from AWS Parameter store like `datasourceUrl`, `dbUserName` etc.
Binding between these values from yaml file and parameterstore is happening correctly in 2.2.6.
But, having issue when I migrated to 2.6.6.Below is the error am getting when ECS service is starting:

Not sure what I am missing in this migration.

```
    org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/orm/jpa/HibernateJpaConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean]: Factory method 'entityManagerFactory' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.RuntimeException: Driver org.postgresql.Driver claims to not accept jdbcUrl, **${datasourceUrl}**
```

Below are updated dependencies I have added as part of this migration.

```xml
        <parent>
           <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
           <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
           <version>2.6.6</version>
           <relativePath/> 
       </parent>

        <!-- Cloud dependencies version used-->

        <spring-cloud.version>2021.0.1</spring-cloud.version>
    
    <!-- AWS Parameter store versions used-->

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-aws</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.6.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
           <groupId>io.awspring.cloud</groupId>
           <artifactId>spring-cloud-aws-parameter-store-config</artifactId>
           <version>2.4.1</version>
        </dependency>
```

Comment: Tried adding config:import:aws-parameterstore: as mentioned https://rieckpil.de/resolving-spring-boot-properties-using-the-aws-parameter-store-ssm/ 
and getting error  "unable to load config data for "aws-parameterstore:" "